# Customising the Link plugin

Tags: python, django, django-cms, wymeditor

I am currently building a multi-site Django website.  I would like to be able to override the functionality of the base link plugin `cms.plugins.link` to be able to link to any other page within any of the other sites.

I'm using the default editor, [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/).

I have already created a custom CMSPlugin abstract model which provides the functionality I need by using the `cms.models.fields.PageField` class and am using it within bespoke plugins.

What I'm unsure about is how (or if) I can either change the existing `cms.plugins.link` model or somehow extend this.  I need to have this modified plugin available within the *Available Plugins* list in a simple `cms.plugins.text` instance.

For what it's worth, the code for my custom plugin follows:

```
class PluginWithLinks(models.Model):
    """
    There are a number of plugins which use links to other on-site or off-site
    pages or offsite. This information is abstracted out here. Simply extend
    this class if you need a class which has links as a core part of its
    functionality.
    """
    page_link = PageField(
        verbose_name="page",
        help_text="Select an existing page to link to.",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    url = models.CharField(
        "link", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True,
        help_text="Destination URL. If chosen, this will be used instead of \
the page link. Must include http://")
    link_text = models.CharField(
        blank=True, null=True, max_length=100, default='More', help_text='The \
link text to be displayed.')
    target = models.CharField(
        "target", blank=True, max_length=100,
        choices=((
            ("", "same window"),
            ("_blank", "new window"),
            ("_parent", "parent window"),
            ("_top", "topmost frame"),
        ))
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @property
    def link(self):
        if self.url:
            return self.url
        elif self.page_link:
            full_url = "http://%s%s" % (
                self.page_link.site.domain,
                self.page_link.get_absolute_url()
            )
            return full_url
        else:
            return ''
```